# Rails 6 / Turbolinks 5 : turbolinks:load fires multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, turbolinks

I'm working on a fairly new Rails 6 app, and I have an issue with Select2 and Turbolinks. I want a Select2 field on the home page that allows to select a user and visit his profile.

The js file looks like this :

```js
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load',function(e) {
  console.log('fired', e.type);

  $('#home-search-field').select2({
    selectionCssClass : 'home-select2-input'
  });

  $('#home-search-field').on('select2:select', function (e) {
    var user_path = e.params.data.id;
    Turbolinks.visit(user_path);
  });
});
```

It works at first, but when I come back to the home page, there is now 2 search fields. If I click on the home link again, it's 4.

The turbolinks:load event is fired multiple times, and it stacks up. I clicked on the home link until I fired it 28 times at once.

[image]

Apparently it adds 2 events every time I load this page ?

I have no clue.

I tried a lot of solutions to delete the field at some points of the Turbolinks workflow:

```js
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:before-cache', function () {
  $('.select2-container').remove();
});
```

or

```js
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:before-visit', function () {
  $('#home-search-field').select2('destroy');
});
```

These didn't work, but I finally found a hack to stop generating multiple fields : adding this line before I call select2.

```js
if($('#home-search-field').first().data('select2-id')) { return; }
```

So I now have only one field, but I still have dozens of useless events. It can't be healthy. Does anybody knows what's happening?

I suspected my js file structure, since I'm using the new Webpack style for the first time, but there is not much there, it looks pretty standard.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it : the pb was with my js pack loading.

I went from this :

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'home' %>
```

to this :

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'home', 'data-turbolinks-eval': false, defer: true %>
```

and it seems to have solved the pb.

As I finally found in the Turbolinks readme :

> Annotate  elements with data-turbolinks-eval="false" if you do not want Turbolinks to evaluate them after rendering. Note that this annotation will not prevent your browser from evaluating scripts on the initial page load.

The turbolinks:load wasn't fired multiple times : my listener to that event was added multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

It also works to only add

```html
<script data-turbolinks-eval="false">
 ...

</script>
```

To the script tags where you don't want it to eval